# Flask API error converting JSON string to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, flask, rest

I am building my first API in Flask. It shall receive json string from Postman and according to the log in terminal POST request is working, I can see my json string in line 15 in the code print(json_).

However next line is a problem:
query = pd.read_json(json_, orient='index')
This line shall convert json into pd dataframe, so I can convert it to an numpy array and load it into my machine learning model.
Outside of Flask my logic work well, but here code gots broken. I put several print command to trace the code breaking point and it seems to me this query line.
Any suggestions are very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!
Vlad

The complete code for API looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import joblib
import traceback
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])

def predict():

    try:
        json_ = request.json
        print(json_)
        
        query = pd.read_json(json_, orient='index')
        
        print('query', query)
        res = np.array(query).reshape(1,-1)
        print('results', res)
        prediction = rf.predict(res)
        print(prediction)
        return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction)})

    
    except:
            return jsonify({'trace': traceback.format_exc()})     

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        port = int(sys.argv[1]) 
    except:
        port = 12345 
    
    rf = joblib.load('random_forest_model_diabetes_refined_31_5_2021.pkl') # Load ML model
    print ('Model loaded')
    
    app.run(debug=True, port=port)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I replaced my query line

```
query = pd.read_json(json_, orient='index')
```

with:

```
query = pd.json_normalize(json_)
```

It works. I am puzzled.